# Damaged Tank, How did it happen

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-tank, damage

As the title suggests there was this dent on my motorcycle and I'm not sure what happened. Any help is appreciated

[image: damage]

Comment: It got hit - assume when parked because you would know if it happened when riding.

Comment: With so little information to go on, it could be anything. All we know is that it is a Honda and it has a dent. To me, it looks to be like it was knocked over (dropped) and the handlebar impacted the tank.

Comment: Once, when putting my helmet on it slipped from my hand and hit the tank causing a small indentation I didn't notice till a day later. Not this size though. Seeing as it's along a crease line it would have to have been something pretty heavy. But also soft - there's no damage to the paint. Id' look around for something resembling a steel pipe wrapped in cloth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I pointed out in my comment earlier - it has been hit - a possible guess is that a pipe or somesuch has been dropped or bounced off the tank.

The possibility of suction being the cause is, imho, very unlikely given the curvature of the outer tank panels.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two possibilities to this:

1. A vent line has become clogged and this has caused a vacuum condition in your tank, causing it to collapse. I've you've noticed the fuel cap being difficult to get off recently this might be it
2. The tank has been damaged by some sort of impact, either something being dropped on it or possibly a car/truck hit it when it was parked

Comment: I don't believe suction could cause a straight line like that do you? And your point two reads much like my comment....

Comment: Suction is less likely but still a possibility that should be explored @SolarMike. Accident damage is a pretty obvious possibility, it's not as if I wouldn't have thought of it if your comment hadn't been there.

Comment: I've had accident damage before, came downstairs to find my handlebar bent. Someone had knocked my ride over and put it back up, then drove away, as if I wouldn't notice.